# Protecting master password in memory

Tags: encryption, linux, c++

Assuming I want to enter master password only one time at the start of the program, how is this master password usually protected in memory after that? Is the encryption key after being derived from password encrypted again? If yes, by what? Is it store in multiple parts and pieced together only before being used?

How is this sort of stuff usually done? Is it even worth the effort?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that having sensitive data (whether it is the password, or derived key, etc) in memory is **not something that most systems deal with**.

That being said, here are several possible mitigation methods for protecting **private data in-memory**. This could apply to a variety of subjects, Server, Mobile or Desktop. The principals are the same. I'm also not sure which attack vectors you are most interested in. (virus, physical attacks)

1. An obvious first step would be to disable **swap** which is a feature that takes less used 'pages' of memory and writes them to a space on the hard disk. It would be fragmented, but quite possible for the attacker to get data with this method.

   It is possible that some OSes provide a means to store **specially marked memory** that is forbidden from being stored in swap. I've never researched it though, and I am sure it is more complex than your typical runtime variable. If you did it this way, you would no longer need to disable swap on the whole machine taking the performance hit associated.

   @Stephane comments that Windows has an option called CryptProtectMemory which encrypts the memory. I think this is clever as that way only the key would have to be forbidden from swap, instead of each individual piece of sensitive information.
2. As for the Memory itself (swapped or not), if you are logged in as root or as the **same user account** the process is running under, there is a means to **dump all memory** for that given process. Many of the high-level programming languages provide this functionality internally with the same user account conditions.

   - Android solves this problem by providing each app with their own user account in the OS, which gives many additional benefits.
   - Server environments often have services segregated into alternate user accounts to help contain potential breaches, both from a memory and from a file-system storage perspective. (never run a public-facing service as root!)
   - In a traditional desktop environment, there's not much you could do to secure processes running in the same user account.
3. The last possibility would be a special hardware module (either to store the data, or an encryption key for the data) which is separated from the main operating system. I would suggest taking a brief look at Trusted Execution Environment (TEE) and/or Secure Element (SE). See [Android Keystore System](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html).

   There is also the more extreme method of using a completely separate (small) computer, i.e. Raspberry PI.

   Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/36636
4. Specifically to your example of a Master Password, you could of course not store the overall master password, but just final password that was extracted from the store. This way the user has to re-enter the Master Password when visiting a new site.

Comment: I'm mostly worried about viruses. Device to which attacker has physical access I believe cannot be protected. 1) not an issue for me, swap (and filesystem) is encrypted 2) running stuff other special users is a good idea 3) my program will already run on Raspberry Pi, so using second one to provide this seems overkill.. Some TEE/SE over GPIO (maybe using arduino) could be interesting idea though 4) in my case I want to enter the master password once per run of the program, so that's not an possibility. So to sum it up if I understood correctly: use separate user account and consider it solved?

Comment: I would say Yes. Viruses should be restricted to whichever user account they were launched on. Of course all the typical virus possibilities such as screen scraper, keylogger, etc. sound like they would be relevant to your situations even if the master password were on a separate account.

Comment: You might want to add that some OS (Windows, for instance) provide a set of APIs specifically designed to encrypt data in memory (CryptProtectMemory).